# Java Abstract Classes: Returning "this" pointer for derived classes

Tags: java, design-patterns

I am trying to write some custom exceptions with helper methods for setting the variables like this:

```
public class KeyException extends RuntimeException {
    protected String Id;

    protected KeyException(String message) {
        super(message);
    }

    protected KeyException(String message, Throwable cause) {
        super(message, cause);
    }

    public String getId() {
        return keyId;
    }

    public KeyException withId(final String Id) {
        this.Id = Id;
        return this;
    }
}
```

However, in my derived classes, I cannot use the "withId" method as it only returns the base class - is there anyway to return the "this" pointer without having to override the method in every single derived class?

Comment: `this` will refer to the current object, so it will be the type of a Derived class, if you are using a derived type object.

Comment: @silverback This doesn't change the return type so the compiler doesn't know the type is `Derived`

Comment: I have left it like that, but when I create an instance of a derived type, it always returns the base type so I am unable to use the methods

Comment: I was going to suggest: `class KeyException<T extends KeyException> { public T withId(); } ` but Exceptions aren't allowed to have generic signatures.

Comment: You can't reference a Derived class within a Base class. It doesn't know of any Derived classes. Where you are using this method, you may have to cast the value as in `DerivedException e = (DerivedException) obj.withId("somestring");`

Comment: But they are allowed to have generic methods.

Comment: Why do you need the reference to `this`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> is there anyway to return the "this" pointer without having to override the method in every single derived class?

Yes, look at the option 1 below.

There are several ways you can do here:

1. **Cast the result to the derived class**
2. Override it in subclasses
3. Change return type to void. Since you're invoking a method on an object, you already have a pointer to it.

Comment: Went with this option, even though it was a bit more hassle it achieved what I wanted to do, which seems to be impossible the way I wanted it!

Answer (score 11):

You can do something like this:

```
public <T extends KeyException> T withId(final String Id) {
    this.Id = Id;
    return (T)this;
}
```

Then in your derived class you just pass its type as a type parameter.

There may be a design oversight however. Apart from the builder pattern I rarely see setters return a reference to the object itself. If you would provide more context we would be able to help you more.

Comment: Apart from the builder pattern, you have all other implementations of the [Fluent interface](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluent_interface) :-)

Answer (score 5):

It's possible with generics using the following construct:

```
public class ParentType<T extends ParentType<T>> {
    public T withId(String someId) {
        /* Insert other code here */
        return (T) this;
    }
}

public class BranchType<T extends BranchType<T>> extends ParentType<T> {}

public final class LeafTypeA extends BranchType<LeafTypeA> {}

public final class LeafTypeB extends ParentType<LeafTypeB> {}
```

Where BranchType is a class with subclasses, and LeafTypeA, LeafTypeB are classes without subclasses.

This is a slight improvement over the other generics solution as it prevents:

```
public class LeafTypeA extends BranchType<LeafTypeB> {}
```

Since this does not satisfy the constraints of the type parameter.

Answer (score 1):

There is one way to solve the return subclass problem using generics:

```
// base class

public class Base<T extends Base> {

  private T myself;

  public Base(T myself, Class<T> cls) {
    this.myself = myself;
  }

  public T withSomething() {
    return myself;
  }
}

// subclass

public class SomeSubCls extends Base<SomeSubCls> {

  public SomeSubCls() {
    super(this, SomeSubCls.class);
  }
}
```

Using this pattern `new SomeSubCls().withSomething()` will return the object as an instance of the subclass, rather than the parent.

Used by [fest assertions](https://github.com/alexruiz/fest-assert-2.x) for instance, check [this](https://github.com/alexruiz/fest-assert-2.x/blob/master/src/main/java/org/fest/assertions/core/NumberAssert.java)

Comment: True, my bad. `a generic class may not extend java.lang.Throwable`.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a derived class, e.g.

```
public class AnotherException extends KeyException {
     ...
}
```

.... then you can simpy asign it using `withId` ....

```
AnotherException a = new AnotherException ("A");
AnotherException b = (AnotherException) a.withId("ID");
```

... because it's basically the same object. You just need to cast it.

Answer (score -2):

unfortunately not.  It would be good if you could do this

```
public this withId(final String Id) { // doesn't work
    this.Id = Id;
    return this;
}
```

or just

```
public this withId(final String Id) { // doesn't work either
    this.Id = Id;
}
```

or it would know that "void" methods are implicitly chained (as I believe one formal proposal suggested)