# Java Abstract Classes: Returning “this” pointer for derived classes "follow up"

Tags: java, inheritance, casting

I need some help on the below post as I am not able to get the derived object out of base object using generics and I wish not to use the downcasting.

[Java Abstract Classes: Returning "this" pointer for derived classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18204190/java-abstract-classes-returning-this-pointer-for-derived-classes)

I am very much interested in seeing the code example set up by @Adam Arold in the post.

```
public <T extends KeyException> T withId(final String Id) {
    this.Id = Id;
    return (T)this;
}
```

I cannot comment on that post as I need rep points to do that, so I am posting new one.

I essentially tried this and I get some warnings,

```
   public class KeyException <T extends KeyException<T>> {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    protected String Id;

    public String getId() {
        return Id;
    }

    // The type parameter T is hiding the type T
    public <T extends KeyException<T>> T withId(final String Id) { 
        this.Id = Id;
        return (T)this; //Type safety: Unchecked cast from KeyException<T> to T
    }
}
```

What would be the correct way to use generics to avoid downcasting ?

My code below,

```
class Foo<TSelf extends Foo<?>> {
    Class<TSelf> selfClass;

    Foo(Class<TSelf> selfClass) {
        if (!this.getClass().equals(selfClass)) 
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        this.selfClass = selfClass;
    }

    TSelf returnThis() {
        return selfClass.cast(this);
    }
}

class Bar extends Foo<Bar> {
    Bar() {
        super(Bar.class);
    }

    public int id = 10;

    public static void main(String str[]) {
        Bar b = new Bar();
        b.id = 10;
        Foo F = new Bar();
        F.returnThis().id = 20; // Error, id cannot be resolved or is not a field
    }
}
```

Implementation of builder pattern with "**Fluent**" interface,

```
// Base Class here

public abstract class Foo {
    protected final String className;

    protected Foo(Builder<?> builder)  {
        this.className = builder.className; 
    }

    /* Builder class */
    public static abstract class Builder<T extends Builder<?>> {
        Class<T> selfClass;

        protected String className;

        public Builder(Class<T> selfClass) {
            if (!this.getClass().equals(selfClass)) 
                throw new IllegalArgumentException();
            this.selfClass = selfClass;
        }                         

        public Builder<?> withClassName(String className) {
            this.className = className;
            return self();
        }

        public T self() { 
            return selfClass.cast(this);
        }

        /* build the Option */
        public abstract Foo build();

        private void validate() {
            if(className != null)
                throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        }
    }     
}

// Derived Class here

public class Bar extends Foo {
    private final String barProp;   

    private Bar(Builder builder) {
        super(builder);
        this.barProp = builder.barProp;
    }

    /* Builder class */
    public static class Builder extends Foo.Builder<Bar.Builder> {
        private String barProp = null;  

        public Builder() {
            super(Bar.Builder.class);
        }

        public Bar.Builder withBarProp(String barProp) {
            this.barProp = barProp;
            return self();
        }

        public Bar build() {
            if(barProp != null)
                throw new IllegalArgumentException();

            return new Bar(this);
        }            
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {         

        Foo f1 = new Bar.Builder()
                    .withBarProp("Prop 1")
                    .withClassName("Bar") // works fine
                    .build();

        Foo f2 = new Bar.Builder()
                    .withClassName("Bar")
                    .withBarProp("Prop 1") // does not work
                    .build();

    }
}
```

Comment: Exceptions aren't allowed to be generic. Is this class just poorly named or have you not tried extending Exception/Throwable yet? Extending would not compile.

Comment: just for the namesake. I am not trying to extend Exception. I just took the example from that previous post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're shadowing the `T` parameter in `withId()`. This means that the `T` used in the method is different than `T` used in the class scope. Just use:

```
public T withId(String id) {
    ...
}
```

That said, what you're trying to do probably can't be made type-safe. `KeyException` simply cannot guarantee that the type of `this` is `T`. The type system cannot express that constraint and I have a hunch that it can't even be made to do so, as in it would cause more trouble than it solves.

The closest you can get to is the still boilerplatey workaround that only works for one level of inheritance:

```
class Foo<TSelf extends Foo> {
    Class<TSelf> selfClass;

    Foo(Class<TSelf> selfClass) {
        if (!this.getClass().equals(selfClass)) 
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        this.selfClass = selfClass;
    }

    TSelf returnThis() {
        return selfClass.cast(this);
    }
}

class Bar extends Foo<Baz> {
    Bar() {
        super(Baz.class);
    }
}
```

This still requires you to spell out what type you want your `withId()` etc... methods to return, but at least you don't have to override each and every one of them.

Comment: thanks for your response, so it seems not possible to downcast straight away using generics. will I have to use some design pattern to overcome the problem ? I have sub class object which needs to have some extra properties to do a common task as specified in base class. The problem is that I have to set those properties (with hiding visibility to other sub objects, therefore can't be part of base) and I have base object to do that. Somehow, I don't want to use the casting-to-derived method to do this.

Comment: @Rustagi Sorry, casting-to-derived is probably your only option. If you REALLY want I could try and come up with a proof why a generic solution wouldn't be type-safe.

Comment: Thanks but I would take your word on that. No need for the proof for something which would not be useful for me.

Comment: @Rustagi Anyway, I came up with a way to at least reduce the amount of boilerplate needed to implement the downcast-to-derived pattern in *some* cases. Unfortunately it won't work for more than one level of inheritance, and you'd have to use `new Foo<Foo>(Foo.class)` to make actual instances of `Foo` which is pretty ludicrous.

Comment: I quickly tested this design with the following code, but I get that unresolved error while accessing derived data through base object. Please let me know if I am adopting your method correctly or not ?

Comment: sorry, I mistakenly edited your post with my code. Please remove it if you get to approve it. Please find my code in my post above.

Comment: @Rustagi "accessing derived data through base object" - clearly this can **never** work. When you're using the base object, you only have access to the function signatures declared on the base class. Methods inherited from and accessed through `Foo` can fundamentally not use the type of the actual object in use. All my generic hack above does is let you avoid having to override every single "fluent" method in a subtype.

Comment: @Rustagi Or, another way to phrase this: the method signatures only use the *compile-time* type of an object (or `T`), not the *runtime* one. `(Foo) new Bar()` has the compile-time type `Foo` and that's all the compiler can ever know.

Comment: thanks for your explanation.. I understand that how can the base class know about the derived members, yet, I was wondering if there is any design pattern which I could use. What do you mean by "fluent" here, just curious ?

Comment: I have provided an implementation of builder pattern with fluent interface, simultaneously incorporating your hack, yet, I am not able to avoid the downcast situation while building the derived objects. Using this pattern forces me to provide the special properties before I can set common properties. Please see the example above in my post above.

Comment: @Rustagi Well you're returning `Builder<?>` from `withClassName()`, you need to return the specific type. That said at this point I feel like you're leeching from me to walk you through your design, consider actually working on it instead of commenting everytime you hit a compiler error. (And if you're stuck, consider posting a new question.)

Comment: sorry if you feel annoying, but your comment helped me and it worked this time.

Answer (score 1):

To avoid the downcast you can pull the `withId` method which needs to return the self-type into an interface. The abstract class can then implement the interface with a self-type of itself. That then allows it to avoid the downcast. Any subclasses of the abstract class can safely return this using return type covariance.

This avoids the downcast but it means that subclasses of the abstract class aren't typed with a self-type, which may be a problem depending on your use cases.

```
public interface IFace<SELF extends IFace<SELF>> {
    SELF withId(String id);
}

abstract class Type1 implements IFace<Type1> {

    @Override
    public Type1 withId(String id) {
        return this;
    }
}

class Type2 extends Type1 {

    @Override
    public Type2 withId(String id) {
        return this;
    }
}
```